# Using ASP.NET MVC v2 EditorFor and DisplayFor with IEnumerable<T> Generic types

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have a `IList<Tag>` as a property named `Tags` in my model. How do I name the files for  display and editor templates to respect it when I call `DisplayFor` or `EditorFor`? Usage:

### Model

```
class MyModel 
{
    IList<Tag> Tags { get; protected set; }
}
```

### View

```
<%= Html.EditorFor(t => t.Tags) %>
```

*edit*
I know I can do this, but its not what I want to do.

```
<%= Html.EditorFor(t => t.Tags, "TagList") %>
```

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Use the attribute [UIHint("Tags")] then create a display template called Tags.ascx in the DisplayTemplates folder.

```
class MyModel 
{
    [UIHint("Tags")]
    IList<Tag> Tags { get; protected set; }
}
```

And in the file Tags.ascx

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl<IEnumerable<Tag>>" %>
<!-- put your Model code here ->
```

Works for me

Comment: That was for the display template, but it should work for the Editor template as well

Comment: And you will need to add "using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;"

Comment: Wow +1 for finding some arcane data annotation :-) Nice one!

Comment: This violates the concept of not using magic strings and destroys the generic abilities of an IEnumerable<T>. This will only ever work for that specific IEnumerable<T> definition. For a better answer IMHO, see http://stackoverflow.com/a/18975211/2453740

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem today. Hope this helps:

```
forach(var tag in Tags) {
    <%= Html.EditorFor( _ -> tag) %>
}
```

If you absolutely want to do sth. like

```
Html.EditorFor(mymodel=>mymodel.Tags)
```

Then you will have to:

Create a UserControl (TagList.ascx) and add an UIHint attribute to MyModel

```
class MyModel {
     [UIHint("Taglist")]
     IList<Tag> Tags {get; protected set;}
}
```

Comment: +1 `<%= Html.EditorFor( _ -> tag) %>` is working great for me with iterating an `IEnumerable<T>` for each of `T`'s properties building a pivoted table

Answer (score 4):

I **had** the same problem as you :-/ but found this useful post which gives you 4 different options to solve the problem :-):

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/stuartleeks/archive/2010/04/01/collections-and-asp-net-mvc-templated-helpers-part-4.aspx

This is also interesting (more or less same solution as one of the solutions in the previous link - but interesting):

http://weblogs.asp.net/rashid/archive/2010/02/09/asp-net-mvc-complex-object-modelmetadata-issue.aspx

Answer (score 2):

EditorFor or DisplayFor is access ViewData.Model property.

Sample solution

```
<% foreach(var tag in Model.Tags) { %>
<%= Html.EditorFor(m => tag) %>
<% } %>
```

Other solution

```
<% for (var i=0;i<Model.Tags.Count();i++) { %>
<%= Html.EditorFor(m => m.Tags[i]) %>
<% } %>
```

Hope this code!

Comment: I don't want to iterate it. I am building a StackOverflow like text box for picking tags.

Comment: This is not a solution, but a diversion from the problem

Answer (score 2):

You could create a custom collection type and name the editor to match that.

Assuming you created custom collection called `Tags` you could change your model to:

```
class MyModel
{
   Tags Tags { get; protected set;}
}
```

Then you would name your editor and display templates `Tags.ascx`.

Which would make your view code work like you wanted:

```
<%= Html.EditorFor(t => t.Tags) %>
```

For the custom collection you basically just create a wrapper around an implementation of a generic collection and expose it's methods and properties:

```
public class Tags : IList<Tag>
{
    //Use a private List<Tag> to do all the 
    //heavy lifting.
    private List<Tag> _tags;

    public Tags()
    {
        _tags = new List<Tag>();
    }

    public Tags(IEnumerable<Tag> tags)
    {
        _tags = new List<Tag>(tags);
    }

    #region Implementation of IEnumerable

    public IEnumerator<Tag> GetEnumerator()
    {
        return _tags.GetEnumerator();
    }

    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return _tags.GetEnumerator();
    }

    #endregion

    #region Implementation of ICollection<Tag>

    public void Add(Tag tag)
    {
        _tags.Add(tag);
    }

    public void Clear()
    {
        _tags.Clear();
    }

    public bool Contains(Tag tag)
    {
        return _tags.Contains(tag);
    }

    public void CopyTo(Tag[] array, int arrayIndex)
    {
        _tags.CopyTo(array, arrayIndex);
    }

    public bool Remove(Tag tag)
    {
        return _tags.Remove(tag);
    }

    public int Count
    {
        get { return _tags.Count; }
    }

    public bool IsReadOnly
    {
        get { return false; }
    }

    #endregion

    #region Implementation of IList<Tag>

    public int IndexOf(Tag tag)
    {
        return _tags.IndexOf(tag);
    }

    public void Insert(int index, Tag tag)
    {
        _tags.Insert(index, tag);
    }

    public void RemoveAt(int index)
    {
        _tags.RemoveAt(index);
    }

    public Tag this[int index]
    {
        get { return _tags[index]; }
        set { _tags[index] = value; }
    }

    #endregion
}
```

Comment: I thought they create Generics just to avoid this :)

Comment: This has a bad code smell - violates the DRY principle spectacularly IMO :-)

Answer (score 2):

Throw [this HtmlHelperExtension.cs file](https://github.com/davemorgantexas/MVCStuff/blob/master/Extensions/HtmlHelperExtension.cs) in your project, then just use:

```
<%= Html.EditorForMany(t => t.Tags) %>
```

You may also may specify a template for the individual items:

```
<%= Html.EditorForMany(t => t.Tags, "MySingularTagTemplate") %>
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer, as it supports generic enumerables.