# MVC IEnumerable of EditorFor Template; how to get the count

Tags: model-view-controller, templates, view, count, ienumerable

ViewModel:

```
public class Foo {
    IEnumerable<Bar> Bars { get; set; }
```

Foo Template:

```
@Html.EditorFor(x => x.Bars)
```

Bar Template:

```
//this is the closest I could find 
@ViewData.TemplateInfo.HtmlFieldPrefix //equals "Bars[0]" on the first iteration
```

Is there a way to get the count of the current iteration inside the template during the render process? Aside from parsing the HtmlFieldPrefix string into a count.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could you restructure your view so that it did something like this:

```
@for( int idx = 0; idx < Model.Count; idx++ )
{
    @Html.EditorFor(m=>m[idx])
}
```

Apologies if IEnumerable<> doesn't support Count, but if it doesn't you could use some other collection which does.

Answer (score 0):

Just to share here since this question useful to me and [`UIHint` and template](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2188052/186334) help me too.

I stick not to touch the Foo template but count should be displayed in the Bar template. so this is how `EditorFor` handle `IEnumerable`.

1. I will use `ICollection` because EF does not support `IEnumerable` for lazy loading. `ICollection` has `Count` property.
2. Even if I need to use `IEnumerable`. I will iterate through the collection and do `i++`. Later, after the iteration or foreach finished, `i` is the total.