# Dynamically add new fields with Editor Template

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, mvc-editor-templates

In my MVC4 project I have a Category view model with a collection of Product view models. I use an Editor Template to render a single Product view model, and pass the collection of Product view models to it:

Category view model:

```
@model CategoryViewModel
@using MVC4PartialViews.Models.ViewModels

<div class="editor-field">
    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.CategoryName)
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.CategoryName)
</div>

@Html.EditorFor(x => x.Products)
```

Editor template that renders each Product in the collection:

```
<div class="editor-field">
    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.ProductName)
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ProductName)
</div>
// etc.
```

This works very well as it automagically names and indexes the elements correctly so all the Products get posted back as part of the parent Category view model - here's what it outputs:

```
<div class="editor-field">
    <input class="text-box single-line" id="Products_0__ProductName" name="Products[0].ProductName" type="text" value="Add 1st product for this Category" />
    <span class="field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="Products[0].ProductName" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span> 
</div>
```

I need to lets users add and remove Products. To add a new one I somehow need to dynamically render the editor template to create the new Product and have each field indexed / named correctly i.e if I already have 2 Products (indexed 0 and 1) then the new Product would need to be named as such:

```
Products[2].ProductName
```

I've read this article by Steve Sanderson but it seems clunky and he indexes his fields with a Guid rather than a consecutive index field:

[Editing a variable length list in MVC2](http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2010/01/28/editing-a-variable-length-list-aspnet-mvc-2-style/)

TIA

Comment: Did you ever done what you were looking for? I am of the same opinion and asking the same question. If you did, can you share how? Thanks

Comment: @Display Name I moved onto something else after this post but I'm back on it again. I downloaded the code sample from the Steve Sanderson link above which works but he uses a GUID as an index. I'm going to try again and see can I get his code to work using a consecutive index

Comment: @DisplayName I found another article by Steve Sanderson where he does what I need but uses Knockout.js. I tried to incorporate his code in my project but the postback to my Controller won't work - it doesn't send back any data. So still looking for a solution for this :-| Here's the article: http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2010/07/12/editing-a-variable-length-list-knockout-style/

Comment: Thanks for sharing your experinece. Wanting to learn knockout js too, haven't got time, feels like using it **much more appropriate** than straighforward ASP.NET MVC approach Steve applying using GUIDs

Comment: This question is a duplicate of multiple similar questions on StackOverflow. Search for "editing variable collection/list" and similar

Answer (score 0):

Not to late to answer here,

I am looking for something the link you provide useful to me. Now I know how upload file input can be add dynamically by using add/remove item in `IEnumerable` property of model in `EditorFor`.

For your solution, I think [`UIHint` and template](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2188052/186334) can do whatever you wanted to do. Inside the template you can `foreach` and specify the formatting for `id`.

Answer (score 0):

Checkout the solution outlined in Jarrett Meyer's blog post, [Nested Collection Models in MVC3](http://jarrettmeyer.com/post/2995732471/nested-collection-models-in-asp-net-mvc-3).
Summarized in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14699615/mvc4-how-to-dynamically-add-line-item-to-editorfor-field/23495834#23495834) on SO.