# MVC4 Template for IEnumerable

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, templates

I want to create a template for IEnumerable.

I know if i make a template for Employee and call DisplayFor, it will create for the whole list, but i want to get a table from template.

If i name the cshtml file as Employee, then DisplayFor method, when used for a single Employee throws an error because it expects a Collection, if i name Collection, it tries to use for all the Collections.

So, is there a way i can name a template that is called only for IEnumerable?.

Edit - My Template

```
@model IEnumerable<LearningViews.Models.Employee>
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Company</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @foreach (var item in Model)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>@item.Name</td>
                <td>@item.Company</td>
            </tr>
        }
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Please show the code for the display template you tried to build for `Employee`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Andrei stated, you can explicitly state the name of the template you want, or you can use attributes on the class to achieve the same.

Check this answer for details:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/2188052/109456

Comment: Thanks, just saw it a couple of mins back. Using UIHint i can tell which template to use, thanks a lot